# Better way to slice up a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to take a string with blank spaces and display each word line-by-line in console output.

My javascript code takes a string and creates an array of indexes where spaces are identified using an indexOf() operation. This is then passed through a slice loop which subtracts the different indexes to get a length of the string to slice and the space index to locate it in the existing string. The output is the final console.log and it appears to do what I need it to even when passing in random strings.

```js
var sp = " ";
var myStr = "I am a \"double quoted\" string inside \"double quotes\""
var twoStr = 'I am a string "and I am a string"';
var stringadd = "and I can slice whenever I want."
var threeStr = myStr + sp + twoStr;
var fourStr = threeStr + sp + stringadd;
console.log("string length = ", fourStr.length);

var i = 0;
var n = 0;
var sentence = [i];
for (n = 0; n < fourStr.length; n++) {
  var pos = fourStr.indexOf(sp, n) //find the index of the space
  if (n == pos) {
    sentence[i] = pos; //place the index in an array
    i++;
  } else(i);
}

var arraysent = fourStr.split(sp); //test split function for string
console.log("Array Sentence:\n", arraysent)

console.log("space index length:\n", sentence.length) //check array length
console.log("space index array:\n", sentence) //display array with "space" indexes
console.log("sliced string:\n", fourStr.slice(sentence[0] - 1, sentence[0])); //display first index 

var j = 0;
for (j = 0; j < sentence.length; j++) {
  var slicesent = fourStr.slice(sentence[j], sentence[j + 1]); //automate remaining index display
  console.log(slicesent);
}
```

I was hoping to find an easier/simpler way to do this same task since passing the string to the array is not efficient and re-creates the string a bunch of times. Could someone please explain a better alternative that will show the individual words of a string line-by-line in the console?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(fourStr.split(" "))`?

Comment: You only need to output the words? What is it with `sentence` Array of indexes? Otherwise that's just `fourStr.split(' ').forEach(word => console.log(word))`

Comment: @MarkMeyer The question is unclear but *"show the individual words of a string line-by-line in the console"*

Comment: Yes @Kaiido, I got  that part (you can just join `console.log(fourStr.split(" ").join('\n'))`), it just seems like there is so much other code, I thought we were missing something.

Comment: Thanks @Kalido. This is exactly what I was hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is literally done by `String.split()`

```js
function logWordsBySpaces(str){
   let arr = str.split(" ");

   arr.forEach(function(a){ console.log(a); })
}

logWordsBySpaces("Karma karma karma karma karma chameleon!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.split`

```js
var sp = " ";
var myStr = "I am a \"double quoted\" string inside \"double quotes\""
var twoStr = 'I am a string "and I am a string"';
var stringadd = "and I can slice whenever I want."
var threeStr = myStr + sp + twoStr;
var fourStr = threeStr + sp + stringadd;


const result = [myStr, twoStr, stringadd, threeStr, fourStr].map(string => string.split(sp));

console.log(result);
```